# ASP.NET MVC 5 Pass Master Detail View to Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Let say I have a master detail class like this:

```csharp
public class CustomerOrder
{
  public string CustomerID { get; set; }
  public Branch VBranch { get; set; }
  public DateTime TransDate { get; set; }           
  public List<CustomerOrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
    
public class CustomerOrderDetail {
  public Product prod { get; set; }
  public int Qty { get; set; }
  public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(CustomerOrder data) { }
```

Submit JQuery

```
var listDetail = [];
function CollectDetail()
{
    $('table tbody tr)').each(function (idx, item) {
            listDetail.push({
                "Product.ProductID": $('select[name="Product.ProductID"]', this).val(),
                "Qty": $('input[name="Qty"]', this).val(),
                "Price": $('input[name="Price"]', this).val()
        }
    });
}
    function Submit()
    {
        var datas = {
            "CustomerID": $('#customerID').val(),
            "VBranch.BranchCode": $('#VBranch_BranchCode').val(),
            "TransDate": moment($('#TransDate').val(), "DD/MMM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            "OrderDetails": listDetail
        };
    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: JSON.stringify(datas),
                //data:  $('#formCreateEdit').serialize(),
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "CustomerOrder")',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Success')
                },
                error: function (status, xhr, tokek) {
                    console.log(status.responseText);
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            });
    }
```

When I submit the form using jQuery AJAX, the `CustomerOrder` is bound but `CustomerOrderDetail` is always `null`. When I check the output of `JSON.Stringify(datas)`, `CustomerOrderDetil` exists.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Without seeing the data you're sending in the request, or the request itself, we can't really help you

Comment: I have edited and added logic submit

Comment: off topic:  `datas` - note that `data` is already plural, like "sheep"

Comment: In the code provided, `CollectDetail()` is never called, so `OrderDetails: listDetail` won't be set.  Make sure you call it inside `Submit()` as well.

Comment: I would guess that `listDetail.push({ "Product.ProductID": ...` needs to be `listDetail.push({ "Product": { "ProductID": ...`